# Convert SQL to laravel 5 ORM

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am new to laravel kindly help me in learning
Main Idea I have two tables (Users,Pins) 
**"Users"** table contains all employees including admin employee **(Manager)** and **regular employee**.
Every employee can have many pin in **"pins"** table

I want to get all employee of specific admin and their pins count.

Here is query that works, but i want this in ORM.

```
SELECT admin.email ,p.user_id ,COUNT(p.user_id) 
    FROM users as u 
      join users as admin on u.id = admin.admin_id 
      join pins as p on admin.id = p.user_id 
     and u.id = 2 
   GROUP BY admin.email,p.user_id
```

Comment: Hi, can you share the PHP/laravel code you've tried so far? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use ORM in laravel replace your query with this one.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
          ->join('users', 'u.id', '=', 'admin.admin_id')
          ->join('pins', 'admin.id', '=', 'p.user_id')
           ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count,p.user_id'),admin.email,p.user_id)
->and(u.id = 2)
->groupBy('admin.email')
->groupBy('p.user_id)->get();
```